# Avoiding directory listing after turning DirectorySlash Off

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website file structure is as follows:

```
.htaccess (No:1)
/application
/library
/public
    /static
    index.php
    .htaccess (No:2)
```

**.htaccess (No:1)** contains:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ #The step I tried to avoid directory Listing

RewriteRule ^$ public/   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1  #Redirect everything to public folder
```

**.htaccess (No:2)** contains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
RewriteRule ^$ index.php #rewrite everything (if not a file) to index.php
```

When requested url is "/public" or "/library" or /application"(Please note that **DirectorySlash is Off**), it shows the directory listing of the respective  folder. But when a trailing slash is added, everything works fine -> It gets rewritten to index.php and looks for the Controller.

I tried to avoid the directing listing by placing this code on .htaccess (No:1),already specifed:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/
```

This fixed the problem of "directory listing" except for the public folder.

What I want is to fix this problem of directory lisitng when "/public" is requested.I dont want to make use of methods like "deny from all" or "Options FollowSymlinks" to deny directory listing of public directory, but rewrite it to index.php

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in root .htaccess:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Inside `/public/.htaccess`:

```
DirectorySlash On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Nope! I dont need to redirect from non-slash to slash @anubhava

Comment: When "/public/static" is requested it redirects to /public/static/. But I don't want such redirects

Comment: I want to vanish the existence of "real" directories @anubhava

Comment: To hide directory content, trailing slash must not be removed. You must clarify what is exact problem you are trying to solve and why you don't want given solutions.

Comment: Can directory listing be avoided after switching Directoryslash off in public .htaccess??

Comment: Yes it can be avoided by using `Options -Indexes` at the top of `/public/.htaccess`

Comment: But it wont be rewritten to public/index.php . That's my problem

Comment: Yes that's why my suggested solution is the right one. It will rewrite to `/public/index.php` if you request  `example.com/public/static`